# Update state in class from const

Tags: html, css, reactjs, state

I'm new to React JS and I'm coding a really simple task manager. So, I have all tasks in state element of **MyTodoList** class (*each task has: id, name, description, completed*). Then I draw each task separately with **Task** constant.

I want to implement changing buttons below every task (if task is completed button should be "Done", if not - "Not done").

I do not understand how I can update "completed" attribute (which is in **MyTodoList** class in state) from const **Task**.

Would be grateful for any hint!

Code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function DoneButton({onClick}) {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      Done
    </button>
  );
}

function NotDoneButton({onClick}) {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>
      Not done
    </button>
  );
}


const Task = ({id, name,  description, completed}) => {
    const handleDoneClick = () => {
      completed= false //something different should be here
    }

    const handleNotDoneClick = () => {
      completed= true //something different should be here
    }

    let button;
    if (completed) {
      button = <DoneButton onClick={handleDoneClick} />
    } else {
      button = <NotDoneButton onClick={handleNotDoneClick} />
    } 
  
    return (
      <div className='task'>
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        <div>{description}</div>
        <div>{completed}</div>
        {button}
      </div>
    )
  }


class MyTodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Walk the dog',
        description: 'Have to walk the dog today',
        completed: false,
      },

    ],

  }

  

  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <header><h1>TO-DO</h1></header>
        <div>{this.state.tasks.map(task => <Task id={task.id} name={task.name} 
        description={task.description} completed={task.completed}/>)}
        </div>

      </div>
      )
        }

}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyTodoList />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never re-assign parameters unless it is the only solution you have, but you should **definitely never** re-assign parameters which you plan to depend on in the render method.

The proper solution would be this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

...

const Task = ({ id, name, description, completed }) => {
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(completed);

  const handleDoneClick = () => {
    setIsCompleted(true);
  };

  const handleNotDoneClick = () => {
    setIsCompleted(false);
  };

  let button;
  if (isCompleted) {
    button = <DoneButton onClick={handleDoneClick} />;
  } else {
    button = <NotDoneButton onClick={handleNotDoneClick} />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="task">
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <div>{description}</div>
      <div>{isCompleted}</div>
      {button}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You need to use local state, in which you will set the initial value (completed, or not completed) which you are receiving from props, and then **change the state, and not the parameter**. Furthermore, continue using the state value of your completed (`isCompleted`) so React will react to its change.

This is not the final solution though, as this will only keep the **local change of the task, and not change the task status in tasks list.**

Basically, if you component **A** holds the **tasks and their complete status**, you need to create a method in the component **A** which will modify the respective task by ID, to the correct status. Then you need to pass the respective method to component **B** which will call the method and pass along the **id** and **complete status (true / false)** The method which is assigned in component **A** will then look through the list of tasks, find the proper task by ID, and assign its new **completed** value you passed from component **B**. After that, react does its thing and automatically updates **completed** prop you passed to component **B**

Working snippet:

```js
function DoneButton({ onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Done</button>;
}

function NotDoneButton({ onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Not done</button>;
}

const Task = ({ id, name, description, completed, onTaskClick }) => {
  const handleDoneClick = () => {
    onTaskClick(id, false);
  };

  const handleNotDoneClick = () => {
    onTaskClick(id, true);
  };

  let button;
  if (completed) {
    button = <DoneButton onClick={handleDoneClick} />;
  } else {
    button = <NotDoneButton onClick={handleNotDoneClick} />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="task">
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <div>{description}</div>
      <div>{completed}</div>
      {button}
    </div>
  );
};

const MyTodoList = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Walk the dog',
      description: 'Have to walk the dog today',
      completed: false,
    }
  ]);

  const onTaskClick = React.useCallback(
    (id, isCompleted) => {
      const updatedTasks = [...tasks].map((task) => {
        if (task.id === id) {
          return {
            ...task,
            completed: isCompleted,
          };
        }

        return task;
      });

      setTasks(updatedTasks);
    },
    [tasks]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>TO-DO</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
        {tasks.map((task) => (
          <Task onTaskClick={onTaskClick} id={task.id} name={task.name} description={task.description} completed={task.completed} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => <MyTodoList />;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Learned about the useCallBack hook in that answer.  And reinforced the use of the spread operator.  For fun I refactored the code a bit by getting rid of one of the buttons:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ltmqvy?file=src/App.js